# Switching between multiple custom markers without tap on marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I'm using Google Maps Android API Utility Library in  my map project to order to show several markers in a map in a clustered way.
I can't find a way to switching between  multiple custom markers without tap on marker.
Does anyone know a solution of this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting you right, you can call the following function on your desired event to switch between the markers without clicking.

```
marker1.showInfoWindow();
marker2.showInfoWindow();
marker3.showInfoWindow();
```

Mark as right if it works for you .:)

P.S: An info window can be hidden by calling hideInfoWindow().

Comment: Nitesh thanks for the answer but you are getting wrong.I have Arraylist  of latitude and longitude and by using Google Maps Android API Utility Library I plot all markers with ClusterManager<Items> mCluster.

Comment: Okay, leme check if i can find something on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move to your marker locations you can use this:

```
private void movingToLocationWithAnimation(double MARKER_LATITUDE, double MARKER_LONGITUDE) {
    Log.i(tag, "Moving to Location: " + latitude + " " + longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(MARKER_LATITUDE, MARKER_LONGITUDE)).zoom(11).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 2000,
            null);

}
```

and please take a look at this, it may help:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/02/googlemap-animation-with-zoom.html

Comment: Milad I don't wanna move current marker position. I give you a example what i am asking. Suppose  I plot 10 markers on map by Arraylist(latitude,longitude) with bouncing effect and  I tap  on first marker as result first marker active and bouncing and when tap 2nd marker 1st marker is disable and 2nd marker is active and bouncing ,but when I have listview with filled with current Arraylist(latitude,longitude) data . and click on third item of listview which contain third marker location .How 2nd marker disable and 3rd marker active and bouncing.